# How to fix this problem in python in pytube?

Tags: python, pytube

Hello i get following error:
`pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns`

My python version: 3.9.2

Can somebody please help me?

My Code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube #pip install pytube3

Folder_Name = ""

#file location
def openLocation():
    global Folder_Name
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if(len(Folder_Name) > 1):
        locationError.config(text=Folder_Name,fg="green")

    else:
        locationError.config(text="Please Choose Folder!!",fg="red")

#donwload video
def DownloadVideo():
    choice = ytdchoices.get()
    url = ytdEntry.get()

    if(len(url)>1):
        ytdError.config(text="")
        yt = YouTube(url)

        if(choice == choices[0]):
            select = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).first()

        elif(choice == choices[1]):
            select = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension='mp4').last()

        elif(choice == choices[2]):
            select = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

        else:
            ytdError.config(text="Paste Link again!!",fg="red")


    #download function
    select.download(Folder_Name)
    ytdError.config(text="Download Completed!!")



root = Tk()
root.title("YTD Downloader")
root.geometry("350x400") #set window
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)#set all content in center.

#Ytd Link Label
ytdLabel = Label(root,text="Enter the URL of the Video",font=("jost",15))
ytdLabel.grid()

#Entry Box
ytdEntryVar = StringVar()
ytdEntry = Entry(root,width=50,textvariable=ytdEntryVar)
ytdEntry.grid()

#Error Msg
ytdError = Label(root,text="Error Msg",fg="red",font=("jost",10))
ytdError.grid()

#Asking save file label
saveLabel = Label(root,text="Save the Video File",font=("jost",15,"bold"))
saveLabel.grid()

#btn of save file
saveEntry = Button(root,width=10,bg="red",fg="white",text="Choose Path",command=openLocation)
saveEntry.grid()

#Error Msg location
locationError = Label(root,text="Error Msg of Path",fg="red",font=("jost",10))
locationError.grid()

#Download Quality
ytdQuality = Label(root,text="Select Quality",font=("jost",15))
ytdQuality.grid()

#combobox
choices = ["720p","144p","Only Audio"]
ytdchoices = ttk.Combobox(root,values=choices)
ytdchoices.grid()

#donwload btn
downloadbtn = Button(root,text="Donwload",width=10,bg="red",fg="white",command=DownloadVideo)
downloadbtn.grid()

#developer Label
developerlabel = Label(root,text="Dream Developers",font=("jost",15))
developerlabel.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install --upgrade pytube` ?

Answer (score 2):

The error `pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns` has been [a known bug](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/614) in pytube. You can either [update the `request.py` file](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/614#issuecomment-724326141). Or the best way is to [update pytube](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/614#issuecomment-748616576):

```sh
python -m pip uninstall pytube pytube3 pytubex
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```